# In AngularJS, the data is showing up only in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got the following getUserData.js:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('UserdataController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/getUserData.php')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.users = res.data;                
        });
});
```

Which works perfectly, a Json is created inside the getUserData.php file, nothing wrong with that.
But when I want to display it inside the index.php file, I only get it to work using ng-repeat, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="UserdataController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            {{user.voornaam}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But how can I display this data ("voornaam" is dutch for first name) without using ng-repeat? I thought it should be something like this, but it doesn't work..

```
<div ng-controller="UserdataController">
    {{users.voornaam}}
</div>
```

Tried for several hours now, and searched all over the place. If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's because `users.vornaam` just does not exists. However instead of showing an error Angular will just show a "blank value".

Check your object strucutre to understand your error. It will be something like

```
Users {
   0:{ vornaam: xyz, ...}, //this is a single "user" which has a vornaam attribute
   1:{ vornaam: xyz, ...},
   2:{ vornaam: xyz, ...}
}
```

As you can see your User**s** object/array itself just does not have a "vornaam" but consists of several objects which then have the requested attribute.

In the above example

```
Users.vornaam
```

will be undefined. But if you try to access it like

```
Users[0].vornaam
```

it will work.

Comment: Wow, thank yo so much!! I'm new into Angular, and this fixed the problem!! Thanks!!